# Solucionar problema de cors en portal azure

Tags: c#, .net, azure

Tengo una API para consumir un servicio subida a mi portal de azure, pero tengo los siguientes problemas:

- > OPTIONS [**ruta de la API**] 404 (Not Found)
- > XMLHttpRequest cannot load [**Ruta de la API**].
  >   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
  >   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
  >   resource. Origin '**Ruta de la API**' is therefore not allowed
  >   access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Quisiera saber si es posible configurar mi maquina virtual para arreglar este problema, o debo agregar al fichero ***web.config*** la configuración correspondiente y subir de nuevo mi API al portal

Answer (score 1):

Es un 404
Significa que no existe
Checa que tengas todo bien configurado en azure y en tu WC
Puedes poner el nodo de configuración del webconfig

Comment: al paecer por alguna razon que yo no se, estaba diferente el cambio de IP publica en mi configuracion y ahora me aparece esto

OPTIONS **API-URL** 405 (Method Not Allowed)
(anonymous)

XMLHttpRequest cannot load **API-URL**. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

Comment: aqui esta la imagen de las reglas de seguridad [imagen reglas seguridad](http://i.imgur.com/dD8xWbP.png)

Comment: aqui dejo el [web config](https://pastebin.com/z1dRK4u2)

Comment: Por lo que veo la interfaz no esta bien configurada en la maquina ya que la aplicacion tiene conexion a la maquina pero no puede hacer nada por cuestion de permisos

Comment: Como podria resolver eso gracias.

Comment: Honestamente es un relajo configurar una maquina virtual, ya que si no te las sabes de todas te puede pasar lo de tu duda. A mi personalmente no me gusta generar Virtual Machines, yo te recomiendo crear una instancia de web application y subir hay tu aplicación, y ya no te debes romper el coco configurando iis, maquinas o interfacez, solo te debes preocupar por tu aplicación corra

Comment: disculpa, pero es web app, o web app + base de datos

Comment: Puedes debes generar una instancias web application para tu web app, y una instancia Datababase para db lo mejor es que para vincularlas basta con el connetionstring y en tu app lo manejas como si fuera conexion directa a sql con usr y pass

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Existen un par de cosas que puedes cambiar para resolver tu problema.

1 - En tu controlador agrega un metodo Options y que solo retorne un OK (si estas en versiones anterior de web api utiliza HttpResponseMessage en vez de IHttpActionResult)

```
    [HttpOptions]
    public IHttpActionResult Options() {
        return Ok();
    }
```

Esto es necesario para que el cliente conozca que necesita tu servicio API para compartir sus recurso.

2 - necesitas realizar un par de cambios en tu web.config. Dentro del Nodo System.WebServer agrega o reemplaza lo siguiente:

```
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Accept, Cache-Control" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Saludos Cordiales.

Comment: El error que tengo antes de colocar esto es este, `OPTIONS API-URL 405 (Method Not Allowed) (anonymous) XMLHttpRequest cannot load API-URL. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405`, podria esto solucionarlo?

Comment: Estas utilizando el paquete Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors?

Comment: Posiblemente no este usando eso, voy a revisar